# What is faster with item manipulation in Java ArrayList?

Tags: java, performance, object, arraylist

I have to replace an element in an ArrayList.
Which is faster—using `remove()` and `add()` or getting the needed item index and using `set(int, E)`?

If you know some books about similiar themes, please give me some advice.

Comment: Arrays don't have these operations. In an arraylist `set` is highly likely to be the fastest since no resizing or node manipulation will be necessary other than referencing the new object.

Comment: set(int,E)  is better I guess,since it replaces the element directly

Comment: Just wondering: you did some profiling, and you are sure that you really have to worry about such subtleties?

Comment: @GhostCat That's not a subtlety.

Comment: Just as a thought if you have to do that often a LinkedList would be faster to replace elements. However finding a specific element is slower

Comment: @assylias Only only if you are processing so many items that it matters. Too often people are focused on saving some nanoseconds here or there; as if that would matter unless you do something a zillion times per second. Sure, it is an easy call, and the sane thing to use set() instead of add/remove ... but well, reminding people to understand what they are doing ... whats wrong with that either.

Comment: @GhostCat There is no good reason to use an O(n) algo when an O(1) algo is available (and simpler in this case). If they had similar complexity I agree it would probably be a waste of time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `remove(Object)` will perform a linear search in your ArrayList and then remove the first occurrence of the specified object, which means that in the worst case you'll get an O(N) complexity.

If you already know the index to replace, for sure will be faster to call `.set(index, object)`, but if you don't, there is no difference because in both cases you will have to perform a linear search getting O(N) complexity.

`add(Object)` always add the object at the end of the ArrayList, so it runs in O(1) complexity to add a single object in your ArrayList.

Answer (score 2):

If this is the last item of ArrayList, almost no difference. In othe case - set(int, E) will be faster because no nee to copy part of array

Answer (score 2):

It's all in the [javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html) (emphasis mine):

> The size, isEmpty, get, ***set***, iterator, and listIterator operations ***run in constant time***. The add operation runs in amortized constant time, that is, adding n elements requires O(n) time. All of the other operations run in linear time (roughly speaking).

To recap: set = O(1) whereas add/remove = O(n) ==> **use set**.